# Unwanted _1 in dplyr summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's an example of a summary table in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

category <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
col1 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
col2 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
tbl <- as_tibble(data.frame(category, col1, col2))

sum_tbl <- tbl %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    summarize(across(everything(), list(sum)))
print(sum_tbl)
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
category col1_1 col2_1
<chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A           2      2
2 B           1      2
```

I don't understand where the `_1` of the columns are coming from. How do I get rid of them? Keep in mind that this is a toy example, and my actual tbl has hundreds of columns.

Comment: I think it's because you use a list of functions for `.fns`. Try using `across(everything(), sum)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @aosmith it is because you have used `list()` while applying the function. `list()` is generally used to apply more than one function where `_1` is the suffix for 1st function, `_2` for second function and so on.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), list(sum, mean)))

#  category col1_1 col1_2 col2_1 col2_2
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A             2  0.667      2  0.667
#2 B             1  0.5        2  1
```

Or use a named list to get meaningful column names.

```
tbl %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), list(sum = sum, mean = mean)))

# category col1_sum col1_mean col2_sum col2_mean
#  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A               2     0.667        2     0.667
#2 B               1     0.5          2     1
```

When you want to apply a single function you can do that directly.

```
tbl %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = sum))

#  category  col1  col2
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A            2     2
#2 B            1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could change the `.names` if we are adding the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
     summarize(across(everything(), list(sum), .names = "{.col}"))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  category  col1  col2
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 A            2     2
2 B            1     2
```